# How to solve programming error when storing pandas data frame to snowflake

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, amazon-sagemaker, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy to store a data frame I created in sagemaker to snowflake. The code only works with certain columns. When I add other columns it gives me an error even though they have the same data type. In the following example, if I only upload TA_ID it works, yet if I upload Cluster_ID, the code throws me an error.

I checked SQLAlchemy website but didn't find much information on programming error.

### SQL codes used to create table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.m (
    TA_ID string,
     Cluster_ID string
)
```

### Python code

```
master2.to_sql(name='m', con=engine2, if_exists='append',  schema='test',index=False, index_label=None, chunksize=2000 )
```

ProgrammingError:

```
(snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 29
invalid identifier '"Cluster_ID"' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO test.m ("TA_ID", "Cluster_ID") VALUES (%(TA_ID)s, %(Cluster_ID)s)'] [parameters: ({'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '0'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '16'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '40'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '15'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '29'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '23'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '9'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '25'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '42'}, {'TA_ID': 'TA007', 'Cluster_ID': '28'})] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing column name of cluster_id to c_id and then inserting the data?

Answer (score 0):

You've double-quoted the identifiers in the SQL.  I.e., "Cluster_ID".
If you didn't create the table with the column name also double-quoted, then your SQL must exactly the case of the column name.

So:

```
create table foo (
  "Column_ID" varchar 
);

select column_id from foo;  -- fails
select Column_ID from foo;  -- fails
select "Column_id" from foo;  -- fails
select "Column_ID" from foo;  -- succeeds
```

However:

```
create table foo (
  Column_ID varchar
);

select column_id from foo;  -- succeeds
select Column_ID from foo;  -- succeeds
```

I would recommend that you remove the double-quotes from your SQL statement and see if it can resolve properly. If that still fails, make sure the case of your SQL exactly matches the defined column name.

-Paul-